# javascript: load external library correctly

Tags: javascript

I am very new to this. I am trying to generate a QR code and display it in my HTMl page.

I used this code:

```html
/* Load the library */
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>

/* Basic and simple one */
<div id="qrcode"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "https://webisora.com");
</script>
```

And when put into a div, this displays a QR code as whished.

Now I tried putting it into another file from which all javascript is loaded (and already working)

So i just put it into this function which will be called upon page load:

```js
function LoadQRCode() {
  var src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"

  var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    text: "https://webisora.com",
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark: "#5868bf",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
  });
}
```

And the div:

```html
<div class="qrcodecontainer">
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
</div>
```

But as no suprise, the console states that: `Uncaught ReferenceError: QRCode is not defined`

Which makes sense, as I dont know how to connect the loading of the libraray and he load of the QRCode variable.

But again, this code works when called directly from HTML.

HOw can I alter my function to also give me the same result?

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to load script like:
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>,  var src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js" this will assign value to var src;

Comment: Do I load the librarby from the HTML file and NOT from the JS file?

Comment: Yes load it in HTML.

Comment: ah, that was easy. please reply as answer so I can mark :) thank you!!

Comment: Added as answer.

Comment: ofc, but you always have to wait 10 min before accepting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load script like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

var src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js", this will assign value to var src;

Load script in html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will make sense

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrcodejs/1.0.0/qrcode.min.js" integrity="sha512-CNgIRecGo7nphbeZ04Sc13ka07paqdeTu0WR1IM4kNcpmBAUSHSQX0FslNhTDadL4O5SAGapGt4FodqL8My0mA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
        text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        colorDark : "red",
        colorLight : "white",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```